# Tapestry loop through hashmap

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm trying to loop through a hashmap and display a number checkboxes with id the key of the hashmap and label the value of the hashmap. Anyone knows how the tapestry syntax for that is?

Cheers
Dimitris

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to loop through the key set like this:

```
<form t:type="Form">
    <t:Loop t:source="myMap.keySet()" t:value="currentKey"> 
        <input type="Checkbox" t:type="Checkbox" t:id="checkbox"
            t:value="currentValue"/>
        <label t:type="Label" for="checkbox">${mapValue}</label>
    </t:Loop>
</form>
```

Class file:

```
@Property
private Object currentKey;

@Persist
private Set<String> selection = new HashSet<String>();

public Map<String,String> getMyMap() {
    ...
}

public boolean getCurrentValue() {
     return this.selection.contains(this.currentKey);
}

public void setCurrentValue(final boolean currentValue) {
    final String mapValue = this.getMapValue();

    if (currentValue) {
        this.selection.add(mapValue);
    } else {
        this.selection.remove(mapValue);
    }
}


public String getMapValue() {
    return this.getMyMap().get(this.currentKey);
}
```

I haven't compiled this, but it should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That's exactly what I was searching for. Had to add a method.
public String getLabelValue(){
     return this.getMyMap().get(this.currentKey);
    }
and change
<label t:type="Label" for="checkbox">${labelValue}</label>
in order to display the values of my HashMap and pass the keys to the next page.

Thanks a lot...