# binding map in tapestry 5

Tags: java, binding, tapestry

in my action class i want to have a map of strings. and in my tml i want to access this map with textfield. something like

```
<t:form>
    <t:textfield value="myMap['key1']"/>
    <t:textfield value="myMap['key2']"/>
...
```

i don't insist on syntax, but is there anything like this currently in tapestry? if not, what do i need to create such conversion in the most easy way? type coercing? custom components? i'm starting to learn tapestry so feel free to be verbose :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to bind your own tml prefix.  There is an example of binding prefixes [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToAddMapBindingPrefix).

We wrote our own prefix for `map` which allows us to get the value in the tml like this:

```
${map:myMap.key1}
```

Comment: thx! much better than mine solution. but requires more work :(

Answer (score 3):

ok, i figured it out. i did a simple component MapField:

```
@Parameter(required=true)
Map<String, String> map;

@Parameter(required=true, allowNull=false, defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
String key;

public String getMapValue() {
    return map.get(key);
}

public void setMapValue(String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

tml:

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <t:textfield value="mapValue"/>
</html>
```

that's it. now we can use it in other tml:

```
<t:mapField key="existingOrNot" t:map="myMap"/>
```

and in a page we need only `myMap` as a property:

```
@Property @Persist Map<String, String> myMap;
```

probably there are more things to be done, like passing all additional html parameters to the textfield, etc

Answer (score 2):

you will need to create an accessor method in your java class.

the most straightforward way would be to add a single method:

`getMapValue(String key){...}`

you can then change your tml to use

`value="getMapValue('key1')"`

Comment: this way it is read only so i can't use it in a text field, can i? text field requires a setter with a single parameter - the value. so there is no place to pass the key

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to loop through the key set like this:

```
<form t:type="Form">
    <t:Loop t:source="myMap.keySet()" t:value="currentKey"> 
        <input type="text" t:type="Textfield" t:value="currentValue"/>
    </t:Loop>
</form>
```

You'll have to add some code in the class file that stores the current map key and gives access to the current value:

```
@Property
private Object currentKey;

@Persist
@Property
private Map<String,String> myMap;

public String getCurrentValue() {
     return this.myMap.get(this.currentKey);
}

public void setCurrentValue(final String currentValue) {   
    this.myMap.put(this.currentKey, currentValue);
}
```

(This answer is adapted from one of my [earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433410/tapestry-loop-through-hashmap/2434992#2434992).)

Comment: this way i have to iterate through whole map even if i want just a few keys. i also cannot add entries for keys that are not already in the map